# Debugger not stepping through window.close in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome and I have a Javascript code that opens up a popup window, and closes it after it's job is done. My code is similar to this:

```
myWindow = window.open(...); //it opens successfully.
[code here is executed successfully]
myWindow.close(); //can't get after this point
[some more code that I can't reach]
```

I have more code after closing the window but debugger never steps after that point. I've even tried putting `debugger;` after `close` but no avail. The window *does* close fine though.

How can I execute the script after closing a popup window? (obviously, the code is owned by the parent window that is *not* closed)

Comment: you can call another javascript function from that close button, and then set your content to visible

Comment: @BilalZafar which close button? which content? I never mentioned anything like a "close button" or setting a content? please read the question before commenting.

Comment: "I have more code after closing the window" What is this ?

Comment: @BilalZafar it's completely irrelevant. even removing all the code and putting just `debugger;` after close doesn't get hit.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @epascarello nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome.

```
debugger;                 // Stops
var x = '0';              // F10
console.log(x);           // F10
var mW = window.open();   // F10
x = '1';                  // F10
console.log(x);           // F10
mW.close();               // F10
debugger;                 // Skipped
x = '2';                  
debugger;                 // Stops
console.log(x);           // F10
```

It looks like you can't stop on a debugger immediately after a `window.close()`, unless some other code has executed first - such as an assignment, or a `console.log`. Even setting a breakpoint on the first statement *after* `window.close()` will not cause the debugger to break again -- but placing a breakpoint on the line *after* the one immediately following `window.close()` *will* cause the debugger to break.

Probably not a satisfactory answer, but unless the Chrome team come on to Stack themselves, or a bug is raised with the Chromium project, I doubt we'll get much more than that...

Comment: interesting.. seems that I've stumbled upon a real corner case here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move Your code to `.onbeforeunload` function like this:

```
myWindow = window.open(...); //it opens successfully.
myWindow.onbeforeunload = function() {
    [some more code that I can't reach]
}
[code here is executed successfully]
myWindow.close(); //can't get after this point
```